# return only fulfilled promises

Tags: javascript, promise

I do a lot of requests to api. What i need is to return only fulfilled promises, so i can use them after, with json() function.
After some googling i have this code right now and it's seems like doesn't work. What is the correct way of doing so?

```
async function requestAPI(items) {
        var requests = items.map(item => fetch(url).catch(e => e))
        return Promise.all(requests);
      }

getUrls()
  .then(result => requestAPI(result))
  .then(result => Promise.all(result.map(v => v.json())))
```

Comment: `return Promise.all(items.map(item => fetch(url).catch(e => null))).filter(Boolean)` might work.

Comment: @FelixKling I think [allSettled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) would work better?

Comment: Error in executing TypeError: Promise.all(...).filter is not a function

Comment: @yieChug1 added an answer, let me know if it works or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use Promise.allSettled for this which gives status for each promise that is passed to it whether it got fullfilled or failed, below is your updated code

```
async function requestAPI(items) {
    var requests = items.map(item => fetch(url));
    return Promise.allSettled(requests);
}

function getOnlyFulFilled(allResults) {
    const fulfilledResult = [];
    allResults.forEach((result) => {
        if (result.status === "fulfilled") {
            fulfilledResult.push(result.value);
        }
    });
    return fulfilledResult;
}

getUrls()
    .then(result => requestAPI(result))
    .then((allResults) => {
        return getOnlyFulFilled(allResults);
    })
    .then(result => Promise.allSettled(result.map(v => v.json())))
    .then((allResult) => getOnlyFulFilled(allResults));
```

please refer this for more info
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled

Comment: If there is no shorter solution, this code is just what i needed.

Comment: Don't mix `allSettled` with the ugly `.catch(e => e)` approach

Comment: Could you explain why is it ugly. And why minimalistic approach in code isn't better for you?

Comment: @yieChug1 actually .catch(e =>  e) after fetch may hide the errors as error catched by catch will be again returned as a resolved promise, so if you are using Promise.allSettled , you would think that promise has fulfilled but it actualy failed. The answer has already been updated, just remove .catch(e => e) after fetch